# How to use loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I want to implement a "while" loop in my python code to prevent it from giving me value errors all the time, however I can't figure out the correct syntax.
I'm sure that it's a very simple fix, but I'm pretty new to Python.

I've tried using different indents, but that doesn't seem to work.

I've also changed the loop condition from 
"while true:" to 
"loop=0

while loop<1:"
That didn't work.

Here is what I've written:

```
loop=0
while loop<1:
    try:
        print("""
1: Encrypt
2: Decrypt""")
        menu_choice= int(input("Type the number of your operation, and hit enter: "))
        if menu_choice == 1:
            print ("You have selected to encrypt a message.")
            message_encrypt = input("""Enter the message that you wish to encrypt:
""")
            print("""Your encrypted message is:
"""+ message_encrypt)
            break
    except Value Error:
            print ("Invalid input! Please try again.")
```

Whenever I try to run this, it highlights the "except" and says that it's a syntax error. How do I fix this?

EDIT: My question has been solved and answered by [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Doesn’t try and except go on the same indent?

Comment: indentations are very important in Python. `try ` and `except` has to start in the same column. And make sure you don't mix spaces and tabs to create indentations.

Comment: BTW: instead of `while loop<1:` you can use `while True:`. Instead of `""" """` with enter inside you can use `"\n"` in text as enter.

Comment: it has to be `ValueError` without space

Comment: @furas You were correct! Making "ValueError" one word fixed the problem! I appreciate the help. I'm new to this. How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: you can't mark comments but I created Answer below and you can mark it as accepted. Sometimes you have to wait few minutes before you can accept.

Comment: I just accepted your answer. Thank you for helping. I have been working on this for days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: indentations are very important in Python. `try` and `except` has to start in the same column. And make sure you don't mix spaces and tabs to create indentations.

Second: it has to be `ValueError` without space.